# AWS services that support Reserved capacity

Tags: amazon-web-services, reserved

What are the list of all AWS Services that offer Reserved capacity and in turn provide significant discounts on the service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no official reference aside from the pricing pages for each individual service.

Some that I know:

- [Amazon EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/reserved-instances/)
- [Amazon RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/reserved-instances/)
- [Amazon Redshift](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/pricing/)
- [Amazon ElastiCache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/reserved-cache-nodes/)

Also, services that use Amazon EC2 can benefit from Amazon EC2 reserved instances. For example, Amazon Elastic MapReduce (EMR) uses EC2 instances, and will use existing EC2 reserved instances.